# Dictionary is giving \n error, how do I get rid of the \n?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some code that randomly generates a word from the .txt file. I want this word to also print it's matching definition but it's not working

This is what I currently have

```
keywords = {'carrot': 'Green Vegetable.',
            'apple': 'Red or Green fruit.',
            'orange': 'Orange fruit.'}

print ("Here is your keyword")
import random
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
     a = random.choice(list(f))
     print (a)

print (keywords[a])
```

It successfully generates the random keyword but does not show the keyword's definition.
This is the error that shows

```
, line 11, in <module>
    print (keywords[a])
KeyError: 'apple\n'
```

The error, I believe, is suggesting that my keywords.txt file claims that the keyword includes \n but It most certainly does not, I have not typed \n anywhere in my code or my .txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is probably because of whitespace characters, like `\n` or just your regular old space. You can remove them by `random.choice(list(f)).strip()`.

Comment: Will do, it says I need to wait 5 minutes though.

Comment: @user2997652 Sure buddy. I'm glad I could have helped. Since you're new on the site, let me give you a tip, change from `user....` to a real username as soon as you can, it makes you easier to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Lines from file contain new line (`\n`) characters.

You should strip them.

```
>>> 'apple\n'.rstrip()
'apple'

>>> 'apple\n'.rstrip('\r\n') # if you want strip only trailing CR and NL.
'apple'
```

---

```
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
    a = random.choice([line.rstrip() for line in f])
    print (a)
```

Comment: They _might_ have spaces before them, so I just`strip` then all the time ;)

Comment: Sorry I don't know if i'm just being stupid but all my file contains is this, each word a separate line carrot
apple
orange

Comment: @user2997652, `\n` is a line separator. Without it, the file looks like `carrotappleorange`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, It depends on. Sometimes, it is desirable to keep spaces except newlines, and sometimes, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with :

```
a = a.replace('\n','')
```